# Cannot automate localization in my iOS generated App

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization

I am generating an iOS app via some tools. No need to concern about them, I have to do things that way.

### Localization

The app is generated just fine, however I need to have the app be available for a certain set of languages. My app is actually a cross-platform app, and i am handling translation at JavaScript level. So my app actually picks the proper strings.

> I just need to have my app be recognized in the Store as supporting those languages

#### Manual approach

I used to handle this by automatically generating language folders in `Resources`. So my automation scripts, would basically take the list of supported languages (say `it`, `en` and `fr`) and generate the following folders and files in my project:

```
MyApp
|
+-MyApp-Info.plist
+-Resources
  |
  +-en_US
    |
    +-Localizable.strings
  +-it_IT
    |
    +-Localizable.strings
  +-fr_FR
    |
    +-Localizable.strings
```

And `Localizable.strings` is just a placeholder file with a C-style comment in it.

### Not working anymore

This did the trick so far, but now it is not really working anymore. The store recognizes my app to be only an English app, it does not list French and Italian anymore.

I am targeting iOS 8.0+ and developing on latest version of XCode.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the localization folders so they have the ".lproj" suffix.  Use the naming scheme as defined in the Apple Internationalization and Localization Guide under [Managing Strings Files Yourself](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html).

I would also add at least one string resource in the Localizable.strings file for at least one of the languages.  At least one localized string resource may be needed to flip the bits and mark the app as supporting the additional languages.